# How to pass all arguments to a script called by /bin/bash

Tags: bash

I have a script that I want it to receive a number of variable arguments and pass them to the execution of another script, but I'm only being able to pass the first argument set by the first call.

My script (`nodetool_improved`) looks like this:

```
sudo su cassandra -s /bin/bash -c "/usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool -u cassandra -pwf /opt/apps/cassandra/resources/security/jmxremote.password $@"
```

If I call it like:

```
$ nodetool_improved status
```

Then `/usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool` receives `status`, and the output looks OK. But if I call my script like:

```
$ nodetool_improved help status
```

Then the output instead of showing the help for the `status` option, just shows the help for all options, which is effectively the same as calling:

```
$ /usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool help
```

That means that `help status` is not being passed to `/usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool`. Only `help`.

How can I change my `nodetool_improved` script so that all arguments are passed to `/usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool`?

**Some things I've tried and which don't work:**

---

```
sudo su cassandra -s /bin/bash -c "/usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool -u cassandra -pwf /opt/apps/cassandra/resources/security/jmxremote.password -- '$@'"
```

Error:

```
status': -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
status': -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

---

```
sudo su cassandra -s /bin/bash -c '/usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool -u cassandra -pwf /opt/apps/cassandra/resources/security/jmxremote.password "$@"' -- "$@"
```

Error:

Only the `status` gets picked up. The output is the same as if I called it like:

```
/usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool status
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `'$@'` inside double quotes to get the same semantics as `"$@"`. Instead I would pass the arguments outside of the quoted string.

```sh
sudo su cassandra -s /bin/bash -c '/usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool -u cassandra -pwf /opt/apps/cassandra/resources/security/jmxremote.password "$@"' _ "$@"
```

Inside the single quotes you have the literal string `"$@"` which then gets populated by Bash with the arguments to `bash -c '...'` which come after the string. (The `--` is required because the first token after `bash -c '...'` is used to populate `$0`, not `$@`.)

Comment: Only the "status" argument gets picked up. See the edit on my post.

Comment: Then you have something else going on which drops it from `$@` before this runs; or maybe `nodetool` only actually accepts a single argument?  See demo: https://ideone.com/Qbo6GO

Comment: I'm not adding anything besides what I put in my post, it's literally copy+paste. nodetool accepts more than a single argument. See here: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/tools/nodetool/help.html

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but the `cassandra` user has nologin.

Comment: It's working now. You were close though! :) Check this comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1601809/how-to-pass-all-arguments-to-a-script-called-by-bin-bash#comment2441554_1601809

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "--" to stop the parameter interpretation (it works if `nodetool` accepts this using *getopt*). So, try:

```
sudo su cassandra -s /bin/bash -c "/usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool -u cassandra -pwf /opt/apps/cassandra/resources/security/jmxremote.password -- '$@'"
```

Comment: Doesn't work, see my post edit :( I get a "unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'"

Comment: nodetool does take into account "--": https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/tools/nodetool/status.html